# The grace period for editing the posts.

Tags: bug, editing, edit-history, grace-period

So far I was sure that during approximately 5 minutes after posting an answer/question the author can edit it without the changes being documented in the edit history. However in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4027544) the change was documented though it was done in less than one minute after posting.

Is it a new policy or a bug?

Comment: There are exceptions to this, e.g., when a comment is posted. But I cannot see any that would apply in your case.

Comment: To add to quid's comment, the revision history influenced by comments is mentioned here: [Is the 5-minute grace period suddenly gone, or is it just me?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20045)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4027544/revisions) and [the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4027544/timeline) of the answer you linked shows to me the timestamps 09:35:57 and 09:58:00, which is much longer than five minutes.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I am quite  sure that I edited the message almost immediately after posting trying to improve it. I cannot explain the timestamps. But this suggests that the issue is a bug. If it repeats I will report here.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was pretty sure I was only about 20-some seconds into my 4th minute when I added a comma [in this edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4026923/revisions), but it wound up being recorded as an edit to my surprise. If I knew that would have happened, I wouldn't have made this edit (the 3rd or 4th I made after my initial post of the answer), but there's no way to undo it now, and even if there was, it wouldn't really undo things since the real concern I would have is making such a trivial edit when the edit affects the front list of items, which has already happened.